# Android AVD With GoogleApi, Not Getting Network Connection

Tags: android, networking, connectivity, android-virtual-device

I am working on a Windows XP Machine. When running AVDs out of Eclipse, I am getting "No Network Connection" when I am plugged into my company's network and using an AVD that was built with the "Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 7, revision 1".

If I use this same AVD (Google API) and connect to the internet through a Verizon Wireless card, the AVD gets an Internet Connection.

If I use an AVD built with "SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 1", and connect through my company's network, the AVD gets an Internet Connection.

Any ideas what might be blocking this? I am guessing it is something in my company's network, but why only with the AVD created with the Google API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else wants to know, the issue was with our firewall. I had Windows Firewall turned on on my machine. After turning off my Windows Firewall, we were able to spot my activity being blocked on our office firewall.